# simple tensor product of modules over algebras

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, modules, associative-algebras

Let $M$, $N$ be simple modules over associative algebras $A$ and $B$ (over $\mathbb{C}$), respectively. When is $M\otimes N$ simple as a $A\otimes B$-module?

It is right if $A$ or $B$ has a countable basis over $\mathbb{C}$. Are there some other general results?